# 'Installing this Intel generic graphics driver will overwrite any customized driver from your Computer Manufacturer (OEM)'

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates, intel-graphics

Intel Driver and Support Assistant is notifying me of a driver update, but when I go to install the driver update, it gives me the following disclaimer:

> Installing this Intel generic graphics driver will overwrite any customized driver from your Computer
> Manufacturer (OEM).

> OEM drivers are handpicked, customized, and validated to resolve platform-specific issues, enable
> features and enhancements, and improve system stability. Intel’s generic graphics drivers are intended
> for testing, and we recommend using drivers from Hewlett-Packard (HP). Report any issues found with this
> driver to Intel.

Should I follow this disclaimer, or is it safe to install? I've heard that this driver is 'for testing', and I'd rather not install experimental drivers.

Answers on the internet are quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first couple of years [if you're lucky] of a laptop's life, the OEM will keep drivers up to date.
Use them.

After that, your laptop will just 'fall off the grid' & the OEM will no longer care.*

At that point, you need to keep the last OEM installer, but try out Intel's own drivers if you have any issues with a more modern OS/new games etc.

If you don't have any issues, stay on the last OEM driver.

This is the *safest* policy.

*This may sound cynical, but it's what actually happens. Your shiny new laptop will no longer be flavour of the month & driver updates will get fewer & further between, until long before you consign it to the recycle, the OEM will have simply forgotten about it. This will not affect your warranty, just your ability to keep drivers up to date.

Comment: And how long may it take for HP to throw my laptop to the dogs?

Comment: Whenever they feel like it. There's no hard & fast rule. It often comes after they change architecture, so 6 months after they switch from gen 8 to gen 9 of an Intel i7 etc. If it means they need different drivers for those chip families, your old one they'll lose interest in. If it can be done on the same driver, then until gen 10 comes out...